# LEFT_OUTER_JOIN работает как INNER_JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, join, criteria, hibernate-criteria

У меня имеется четыре сущности с которых я хочу вывести все поля в DTO (AllInfoView). Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь получить значения всех полей, LEFT_OUTER_JOIN срабатывает как INNER_JOIN (т.е. выводятся только те строки Video, для которых есть актеры). Что интересно, если я хочу получить поля только Video и Jenre, criteria отрабатывает как LEFT_OUTER_JOIN. Мне нужно вывести в DTO все строки Video в том числе и те, для которых актеры отсутствуют). Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем здесь может быть загвоздка?

Актер:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Actor")
public class Actor {

@Id
@Column(name= "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name= "name")
private String name;

@Column(name= "birthday")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthday;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "sex_id", unique = false, updatable = true)
private ActorSex actorSex;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "video_id", unique = false, updatable = true)
private Video video;
```

Пол актера:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ActorSex {

@Id
@Column(name= "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;


@Column(name= "sex")
private String sex;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "actorSex", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =    FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Actor> actors;
```

Видео, которому может соответствовать несколько актеров

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ActorSex {

@Id
@Column(name= "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;


@Column(name= "sex")
private String sex;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "actorSex", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Actor> actors;
```

Жанр, к которому относится видео:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ActorSex {

@Id
@Column(name= "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;


@Column(name= "sex")
private String sex;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "actorSex", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Actor> actors;
```

DTO:

```
public class AllInfoView {
private Long videoId;
private String videoDescription;
private String videoGenre;

private Long actorId;
private String actorName;
private String actorSex;
private Date actorBirthday;
```

Criteria (выдает результат как при INNER_JOIN):

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Video.class, "video")
                        .createAlias("actors", "actor",  JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
                        .createAlias("video.genre", "genre")
                        .createAlias("actor.actorSex", "sex")

                        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                                        .add(Projections.property("video.id"), "videoId")
                                        .add(Projections.property("video.description"), "videoDescription")
                                        .add(Projections.property("genre.genre"), "videoGenre")
                                        .add(Projections.property("actor.id"), "actorId")
                                        .add(Projections.property("actor.name"), "actorName")
                                          .add(Projections.property("actor.birthday"), "actorBirthday")
                                        .add(Projections.property("sex.sex"), "actorSex")

                        ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AllInfoView.class));
        entitiesList = (ArrayList<AllInfoView>) crit.list();
```

если закомментировать строку

```
 .createAlias("actor.actorSex", "sex")
```

получим результат как при OUTER_JOIN, но не сможем получить значения с таблицы Actor(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам отвечу. Hibernate генерирует следующий запрос: Hibernate генерирует следующий запрос:

```
 select this_.id as y0_, this_.description as y1_, genre2_.genre as y2_, actor1_.id as y3_, actor1_.name as y4_, actor1_.birthday as y5_, sex3_.sex as y6_ from Video this_ left outer join Actor actor1_ on this_.id=actor1_.video_id inner join ActorSex sex3_ on actor1_.sex_id=sex3_.id inner join VideoGenre genre2_ on this_.genre_id=genre2_.id
```

а нам нужно чтоб было:

```
select this_.id as y0_, this_.description as y1_, genre2_.genre as y2_, actor1_.id as y3_, actor1_.name as y4_, actor1_.birthday as y5_, sex3_.sex as y6_ from Video this_ left outer join Actor actor1_ on this_.id=actor1_.video_id left outer join ActorSex sex3_ on actor1_.sex_id=sex3_.id inner join VideoGenre genre2_ on this_.genre_id=genre2_.id
```

добиться этого можно следующим Criteria-запросом:

```
  Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Video.class, "video")
                        .createAlias("actors", "actor", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
                        .createAlias("video.genre", "genre")
                        .createAlias("actor.actorSex", "sex", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)

                        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                                        .add(Projections.property("video.id"), "videoId")
                                        .add(Projections.property("video.description"), "videoDescription")
                                        .add(Projections.property("genre.genre"), "videoGenre")
                                        .add(Projections.property("actor.id"), "actorId")
                                        .add(Projections.property("actor.name"), "actorName")
                                        .add(Projections.property("actor.birthday"), "actorBirthday")
                                        .add(Projections.property("sex.sex"), "actorSex")

                        ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AllInfoView.class));
```